# How to adjust site background with javascript for mobile device?

Tags: javascript, ios, wordpress, mobile, background-image

I've just finished my wordpress website for the cabaret of my friend. I did a bit of Javascript to customize the background image and make every page different from one another. 
Here's what it looks like on my computer.
[Example of my website on Firefox - Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJvo.jpg)

My problem is, when it comes to my iPhone, the result is really not the same...
[Example on my iPhone using Safari for iOS9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZsdA.jpg)

So as you can see, the aspect ratio is really ugly on mobile device.
Here's my code I use on this page to customize my background:

```js
<script>
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://cabarettapisrouge.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/12235379_10207180605785211_985692315_o-e1447975745789.jpg')"; 
document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
document.body.style.backgroundSize= "100% 100%";
</script>
```

So, has you can see, I use proportions 100% on both width and height to adjust my image, but it's not pretty good on mobile since the screen is different. So I know that.

Is there a way I could use external javascript and say to it 'If on mobile device, then show it that way' ? I'm not really good at Javascript for that part...

Even if it's not an external file, maybe I could just pimp my code to make it work?

Anyways, thanks for your help, I'm pretty sure you can all help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try.

```
    document.body.style.backgroundSize= "cover";
```

or

```
    document.body.style.backgroundSize= "contain";
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: This is a great solution thanks! Sadly, for my website, it doesn't seems to work. With Cover, my image is blurry and too big. With contain, it doesn't fill the container.

Answer (score 0):

How about using @media in the css and load one or another image based on each device or view? (Note that '480px' is for the example, and also you can add queries to handle landscape or portrait views, or more resolutions).

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {  
        background-image: url('url to smaller image here...')";
    }
```

Or change the background style depending on the device as:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {  
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Or try CSS `width: 100%; height: auto;` on the background image.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly, the second solution doesn't seem to work...  I will need to do your first solution I think, but it's sad because I'll need to work on new images ahah... Thanks tho!